# white screen showing when open jmeter, can anybody help to resolve this error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

white screen showing when open JMeter, can anybody help to resolve this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNqJN.png)

Comment: Hi  @Reena, Could you provide more details? 1. JMeter version 2. OS  3. JDS version 4. How did you start the JMeter 5. What do you see in the $JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.log 6. Have you done any changes to the JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue and have never seen this behaviour so I can only recommend checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.

If by default it's not too informative you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter" level="debug" />
```

or just [launch JMeter as follows](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override):

```
jmeter -LDEBUG
```

You might want to try a different version of [Java SDK](https://openjdk.java.net/), the minimum version is [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/)